# Update query for multiple values starting with the same name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a set of ids and each id has sub Ids, for example I have an Id 12345 and the sub id for this ID is like (12345_1, 12345_Sub, 12345_john etc).

Like this I have multiple IDs and each IDs have their corresponding sub IDs.

Each Sub ID name starts from their Parent ID name. I trying to update update one column for these set ids and also their sub ids as '**complete**'. So I used the below code, but it is not working and I am not getting any errors.

```
update **DBname/Tablename** 
set **IDStatus**='Complete' 
where **id** like ('12345%', '555656%', '4545454%', '87879898', ..., '14545%');
```

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. Kindly help me. Sorry for my English

Comment: I have no clue what your are talking about.

Comment: if i update one coulum for the ID 12345 as 'completed', the query has to update the same for their sub ids also..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIKE` cannot be applied to a list, you need to connect your expressions with `OR`, like this:

```
UPDATE My_Table
SET IDStatus = 'Complete'
WHERE
    id LIKE '12345%'
 OR id LIKE '555656%'
 OR id LIKE '4545454%'
 OR id LIKE '87879898%'
 OR id LIKE '14545%'
```